# GroceryCRUD hide soft deleted records

Tags: codeigniter-3, grocery-crud

By overriding the `delete` function of `GroceryCRUD` as below, we can easily soft-delete a record.

```
public function user() {
    $crud = new grocery_CRUD();

    $crud->set_table('cms_user');
    $crud->set_subject('User List');
    $crud->required_fields('user_name');

    $crud->columns('user_name','email','real_name','active');
    $crud->change_field_type('active', 'true_false');

    $crud->callback_delete(array($this,'delete_user'));

    $output = $crud->render();

    $this->_example_output($output);
}

public function delete_user($primary_key) {
    return $this->db->update(
        'cms_user',
        array('deleted' => '1'),
        array('id' => $primary_key)
    );
}
```

My question is, How do I hide the soft-deleted records in the Main View ??

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was easy... after some googling it is obvious I can use the `where` clause

`$crud->where('deleted', '0');`

Thank you all... works like a charm